# Identifiying and coloring empty element in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an address book, the XML for which is given by

```
<addressbook>
    <entry>
        <name prefix="Mr.">
            Zack Black</name>
        <address>
            <street>101 Main St</street>
            <city>Searcy</city>
            <state>AR</state>
            <zip>12345</zip>
        </address>
        <phone location="home"
            number="501-279-9999" />
        <phone location="work"
            number="501-279-1111" />
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <name>John Brown</name>
        <phone number="501-305-2222" />
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <name>Susan White</name>
        <address>
            <street>2000 Center Rd</street>
            <city>Dallas</city>
            <state>TX</state>
            <zip>67790</zip>
        </address>
        <phone location="home"
            number="501-279-0000" />
    </entry>
</addressbook>
```

Now, there are a few empty cells. I want to identify them and then color them using some particular color, say red. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by empty cells? Better yet, what you are wanting the output to look like? If you edit that information into your question that would help. Also any attempts you have made that got you close to that output.

Comment: from the given code.. As you can see, there is NO ADDRESS for the element corresponding to John brown. So, my output should be the entire table of data plus the address cell of John brown in Red color.. so that I can easily find out that there is no address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about outputting an HTML table, try something along these lines:

```
...
<td>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@prefix">
            <xsl:value-of select="@prefix"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color: red;</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="'&#160;'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</td>
...
```

You should also explore CSS formatting of empty table cells.

Comment: I cannot use @prefix to select the cells since I want the cells which dont have data..( the address cell for John Brown).. and this was a question posted as a part of a test on XSLT...so, I cannot use CSS in the answer..!

Comment: @user59288 Yes, you can. The example above will create a cell with either the content of `@prefix`, if it exists, or an empty (containing a &nbsp;) cell with a red background.